# Live display of player speed? 1.13.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I saw it in this video at 2m48s:

But author didn't explain how to make it.

Answer (score -1):

This is a mod, while I can't find the exact same one, there's a very similar one [here](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/2181009-squeedometer-adds-a-speedometer-to-your-hud). Installation instructions are on the page.

Comment: That's Xisuma so it's probably a datapack. On the side is a scoreboard that he's probably using to display a calculated speed based on his change in his position.

Comment: there is no version for 1.13.2 :(